# insert multiple data in database using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have Two Arrays i need to insert these two arrays data into database

here is my code

```
$LocaName=$_REQUEST['locname'];
$address=$_REQUEST['address'];

$LocaNamearray = explode("|||", $LocaName);

$addressarray = explode("|||", $address);

for($i=0;$i<count($LocaNamearray);$i++)
{
$query="insert into tbl_MapDetails(LocationName,Address)values('$LocaNamearray[$i]','$addressarray[$i]')";

$result=mysql_query($query);



}
```

so here i need to insert these two arrays at a time into database plz guide me

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be even better if you do something like that

```
$strQuery = "INSERT INTO tbl_MapDetails(LocationName,Address) VALUES ";
$strDelimiter = "";

for($i=0;$i<count($LocaNamearray);$i++)
{
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($LocaNamearray[$i]);
    $address = mysql_real_escape_string($addressarray[$i]);

    $strQuery .= $strDelimiter."('$name', '$address')";
    $strDelimiter = ', ';
}

if($strDelimiter != '')
{
    mysql_query($strQuery);
}
```

Comment: thans for response it works fine so need update also plz guide me

Answer (score 1):

Try using concecation instead

```
$query="insert into  tbl_MapDetails(LocationName,Address)values('".mysql_real_escape_string($LocaNamearray[$i])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($addressarray[$i])."')";
```

Comment: wat about for loop just i mention one array

Comment: @user816891: you're using 2 arrays ther

Comment: ok..here i get two arrays 1)$LocaNamearray 2)$addressarray but here i write one for($LocaNamearray) loop wat about another array

Comment: @user816891: it actually does send the second one, too

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use arrays in a string like that. (Apart from being terrible practice considering sql injections … Better yet to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/pdo.prepare))

```
for($i=0, $c=count($LocaNamearray); $i < $c; ++$i) {
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($LocaNamearray[$i]);
    $address = mysql_real_escape_string($addressarray[$i]);

    $query="insert into tbl_MapDetails(LocationName,Address)values('$name','$address')";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
}
```